# iMac notified me when call comes in on iPhone. How do I turn this back on?

Tags: iphone, macos, imac

A few days ago my iMac would notify me via a tone and a message whenever a call came into my iphone.  This was good for me but my iMac suddenly stopped doing this. How do I turn it back on?

Comment: Your facetime suggestion did the trick. Thank you. If you want to write that as an answer I'll check it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to check.

- Are both devices logged into the same AppleID account?
- Is "Calls From iPhone" checked in FaceTime preferences on your Mac?
- And on your iPhone check the settings under Settings -> Phone -> Calls on Other Devices.